# How can I return a string from an async function?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

```
    class MyHttpClientClass
    {
        public async static string Getrequest(string url, string port)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://" + url + ":" + port + "/"))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This source code gives me a compile-time error:

> The return type of an async method must be `void`, `Task`, or `Task<T>`

How can I return a string from this method without using `out` or `ref`?
I also want to get rid of `async`/`await` pattern.

Comment: You really don't want to get rid of `async/await`. You shouldn't be creating a new HttpClient each time either, it's thread-safe and *meant* to be reused. Reusing it means you don't have to perform DNS resolution for every request too, which can *really* speed up performance*

Comment: This entire method could be replaced with `_httpClient.GetStringAsync(someUrl)`

Comment: As a side note, *`HttpClient` is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an `HttpClient` class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads.* [(citation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient#remarks)

Comment: The problem with socket exhaustion is explained in [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [You're still using HttpClient wrong](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: The solution isn't to avoid HttpClient. You can use [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to get pooled sockets, periodic recycling to handle DNS changes *and* integrate with [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory) to implement retry strategies

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change it to return a `Task<string>`:

```
public async static Task<string> Getrequest(string url, string port)
```

Comment: I want to make it look like an ordinary function. Rather than `Task<string>`, I want to return `string`.

Comment: @user366312 You can't do that as you've opted to use the `async/await` pattern. It has to return either `void`, a `Task` or a `Task<>` type.

Comment: How can I rewrite this to get rid of `async/await`?

Comment: Sean is right. When calling the method you can just do string foo = await GetRequest() and it will return a string object as opposed to the Task.

Comment: @user366312 - You'll need to use an http client class that provides synchronous methods and use this instead. `HttpClient` is aimed at making async requests.

Comment: @user366312 `get rid of async/await` why do that? There's nothing wrong with `async/await` and you *can't* get asynchronous calls without Task<T>.

Comment: @user366312 there are more problems with `Getrequest` too. `HttpClient` is thread-safe and meant to be reused. This can save you the up to 15 seconds needed for DNS resolution. The OS itself pools and reuses sockets, so creating a new HttpClient every time a) can add up to 15s of delay and b) can lead to socket starvation

Answer (score 1):

An async method can only return the following types:

- `void` (not really a return type, used to indicate you do not want to be notified of the completion of underlying task, only useful when attaching an async event handler since delegate type is frozen.)
- `Task` (method does not return a value, sync version would have void return type.)
- `Task<T>` (method returns a task whose result is of type T, sync version would have return type T.)
- `ValueTask` (method does not return a value, uses ValueTask for performance, sync version would have void return type).
- `ValueTask<T>` (method returns a task alike of type T, uses ValueTask for performance, sync version would have return type T.)
- `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` (method returns an async stream of T, new feature introduced in C# 8.0.)

The error message you are seeing is the compiler trying to tell you that you do not meet the expectation. The error message itself is incomplete, even the documentation on async methods on learn.microsoft.com does not mention the last case. Here's the github [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/17127) to track that change.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to async/await, you can use this

```
    public static string Getrequest(string url, string port)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            return client.DownloadString("http://" + url + ":" + port + "/");
        }
    }
```